# FallbackResource not working for .php url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, errordocument, custom-error-pages

Htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

FallbackResource /errordoc.php
```

`FallbackResource`  load content from `errordoc.php` when the file or data does not exist in the server. It working fine for all non-exist url except url ending with `.php`. When url ending with `.php` (`example.com/something.php`) than it ignore `FallbackResource`

How to make `FallbackResource` also work for url ending with `.php`

Comment: Pretty impossible to tell, with the information we got so far. What else have you got in your .htaccess / server configuration, regarding URL rewriting etc.?

Comment: _"How to fix this?"_ - if(?) your intention is _not_ to use this to create some sort of router, but only to show a 404 response for resources that do not actually exist in the file system - then you _should_ be using `ErrorDocument 404`.

Comment: @CBroe updated the question. for some reason i cannot use `ErrorDocument` and i want to use `FallbackResource`

Comment: FallbackResource applies to all requests that can not be mapped onto the file system, it does not differentiate between any specific "file types". What you are experiencing there, can not be explained with the info we got here so far, you'll have to dig a little deeper and see if there is any additional configuration anywhere (VHost, server level) that could be interfering here.

Comment: @CBroe no additional config server level. I am not sure but it does not work with url ending with `.php`. It error or `FallbackResource` does not support `.php`

Comment: This appears to depend on how exactly PHP was added to the web server, https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52403 - _"If you use SetHandler or AddHandler with FallbackResource non-existent PHP file do not use the FallbackResource. With AddType instead of SetHandler or AddHandler the FallbackResource works as expected."_ And it appears that also is the _intended_ behavior, _"This would be expected. The alternate handler is responsible for the content. The FallbackResource applies only to the core file system (default) handler."_